# Custom implementation of robot_localization package

Tags: ros, kalman-filter, imu, visual-odometry

I plan to implement a sensor fusion of IMU + Visual odometry using an EKF. I came across the excellent [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) package which does pretty much all that I want. However, I need to use perform my task without using ROS, and work in an offline setting, where I have a dump of my IMU and Visual odometry data timestamped. Is there a way to use the package as a library, by calling functions as APIs? How would I go about it, has it been done?

If not, are there any alternatives that fuse IMU + visual odometry data using an EKF or a UKF? I ideally wish to code in Python, however I am comfortable in C++ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you not like to use ROS? Seems like if you use this package along with custom code for the rest of the solution it'll be good to go.

> Is there a way to use the package as a library, by calling functions
> as APIs? How would I go about it, has it been done?

It is possible by altering the code to remove ROS dependencies and use the cor filter algorithm in the package. However I won't suggest that. There should probably be other libraries independent of ROS to achieve this. You can try editing the code as a last resort.

I've been using robot_localization package and have been getting satisfying results

Comment: Hello @parzival. The program I am building will ultimately run on a custom robot software stack, and not on ROS. Do you happen to know other libraries that are independent of ROS?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the core filter classes to be ROS-agnostic, but then wrapped them in ROS-aware classes that take in messages, preprocess the data (transform into target frames, check for invalid messages, etc.) and then pass the data into the core filter. You should be able to work with the core filter classes. You'll just want to make sure all the coordinate frames are correct for the data being fused. Velocities should be in the body frame, and poses in the world frame.